# Reducing the number of PreparedStatements used by a spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, prepared-statement

I'm running into a issue with a spring boot application, in which I am getting the below error,

> (conn=1126) Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)

Which seems to be hitting the ceiling of `max_prepared_stmt_count` in mysql. Increasing it as much as we want could be problematic as well as it could result in OOM killer issues like [this](https://blog.searce.com/how-max-prepared-stmt-count-bring-down-the-production-mysql-system-6ca28e577663).

I'm exploring if there are any ways to limit the creation of PreparedStatements in Spring boot.

One possible option that I can think of,

- Avoiding lazy loading whenever possible would force Hibernate to fetch the data with lesser number of prepared statements thus avoiding the problem.
- Cache the PreparedStatements created by hibernate.

If anyone solved this problem or with a deeper insight, please share your wisdom on solving this.

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is why do you have so manu different queries that need to be cached in the first place. Looks like you are generating a lot of different queries.

Comment: Come on! The comment is irrelevant to the problem that I'm facing currently. I'm doing a stress testing so that is expected.

Comment: Not if you have a limited number of queries in your app to begin with. So no that isn't expected if things would behave correctly, which they don't so something is generating queries that are cached and differ ever so slightly. So no the comment isn't irrelevant it is. imho, the key of your problem.

Comment: @KannanRamamoorthy what was the reason to enable Server Prepared Statements (useServerPrepStmts=true)?

Comment: @Andrey B. Panfilov
I'm digging the history to figure out why. Meanwhile, how did you figure out that the flag was set?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has no problem with many prepared statements if they are over time. Obviously some MySQL databases stay up and running for months at a time, serving prepared statements. The total count of prepared statements over those months can be limitless.

The problem is how many prepared statements are cached in the MySQL Server at any given moment.

It has long been a source of trouble for MySQL Server that it allocates a small amount of RAM in the server for each prepared statement, to store the compiled version of the prepared statement and allow it to be executed subsequently. But the server doesn't know if the client will execute it again, so it has to keep that memory allocation indefinitely. The server depends on the client to explicitly deallocate the prepared statement. This can become a problem if the client neglects to "close" its prepared statements. They become long-lived, and eventually all those accumulated data structures take too much RAM in the MySQL Server.

So the variable really should be named `max_prepared_stmts_allocated`, not `max_prepared_stmt_count`. Likewise the status variable [Prepared_stmt_count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Prepared_stmt_count) should be `Prepared_stmts_open` or something like that.

To fix this in your case, I would make sure in the client code that you deallocate prepared statements promptly when you have no more need of them.

If you open a prepared statement using a try-with-resources block, it should automatically be closed at the end of the block.

Otherwise you should call `stmt.close()` explicitly when you're done with it.